# Firebase Data Structure

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to pull all friendId from my Firebase database that are currently "pending". Based on my firebase data below, assuming my currentId is XXX, I would like my script to retrieve friendId ("YYY").

Database Structure

```
friends
 - XXX (currentUserId)
   - YYY (friendId)
     - completed: "pending"
 - ZZZ 
   - AAA 
     - completed: "pending"
```

Function to retrieve pending friends

```
func fetchPendingFriends() {

    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!
    let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("friends").child(currentUser.uid)
    let query = postRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "friendId").queryEqual(toValue: "pending")
    query.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            let friend = Friends(snapshot: childSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)

            self.friendArray.append(friend)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing? what is the output of above code?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is actually save the friendId as a child of your friendId branch.

So have something like this:

```
friends
 - XXX (currentUserId)
   - YYY (friendId)
     - completed: "pending"
     - friendId: "some id"

 - ZZZ 
   - AAA 
     - completed: "pending"
     - friendId: "some id"
```

And you can parse it from there just like how you would parse `completed`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you need to change your database structure a little bit by adding a new node named `pendingList`. You need to do in this way because there is no need to download the entire `friends` object in order to query the database for pending friends. So your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- pendingList
        |
        --- XXX (currentUserId)
        |      |
        |      --- YYY: true  //friendId
        |      |
        |      --- HHH: true  //friendId
        |      |
        |      --- GGG: true  //friendId
        |
        --- ZZZ
           |
           --- TTT: true  //friendId
```

In this way you can simply your query your database for all pending friends that belong to a single user by attaching a listener on `Firebase-root -> pendingList -> currentUserId`